# Negation of expression. Logic

Tags: logic

I need to negate (p OR (notq)) AND (q OR (not r)). The answer cannot use NOT, AND, OR and I got to the point where I cannot see how I can further simplify the expression.
I did the following (please see the image attached): [image: solution]

I would appreciate any hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So close! Just take the contrapositive of the conditional in the hypothesis in order to change $\sim p \implies \sim q$ to $q \implies p$. This is the final answer:
$$(q \implies p) \implies (q \implies r)$$

Answer (score 2):

You can do contraposition on the first half: $\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q = Q \rightarrow P$

Comment: Thank you! I now understand it.